# Checking connection state with WinSCP .NET assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a method for retrying the connection of WinSCP in C#.

How would I know if the state of my connection is opened or closed?  Are there methods for this in WinSCP .Net?

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    try
    {
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //I want to reconnect here if my connection
        //is timed out
        //I want to reconnect here 3 times
    }


    // Upload file
    session.PutFiles(@"C:\Test\files.dat", "var/test/files.dat");

    // I want also to reconnect here if my upload failed
    // reconnect to the server then upload the files that 
    // did not upload because of the connection errors 
}
```

Comment: When do you want to check the state? Show us your code.

Comment: Do you mean a `Session`?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl i want to check the state in opening and if the connection is timed out i want to reconnect again up to 3 times. And also i want to reconnect if the file transfer is disconnected.

Comment: Hi @Default yes the session WinSCP .Net

Comment: You already detect that the connection has timed out by catching an exception. What do you want to test more? - And the `PutFiles` reconnect automatically.

Comment: I mean is there a method like where you can check for state of the session aside from catching the exception? like the Oracle.ConnectionState?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl how is the PutFiles method reconnect? or how many times it will try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you already know, if the connection succeeded or not. Anyway, you can check [`Session.Opened`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#opened), if you want to test explicitly for some reason.

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    int attempts = 3;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect - {0}", e);

            if (attempts == 0)
            {
                // give up
                throw;
            }
        }
        attempts--;
    }
    while (!session.Opened);

    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
}
```

---

The file transfer operations, like the [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles), reconnect automatically, if a connection is lost during transfer.

How long it will keep reconnecting is specified by [`Session.ReconnectTime`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#reconnecttime).

Comment: thank you. I made a already a solution to this but your code is much less short and cleaner thanks